# SQL Server Query to Convert Quarterly and Semi-Annual Principal and Interest Payments to Monthly Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

We are using SQL Server 2014 as a main reporting database and we have report that requires some very specific data manipulation.  The data we have to work with is a schedule of principal and interest payments that can be presented in various types of series (i.e. quarterly, semi-annualy, annualy, etc.).  To determine monthly income, these principal and interest payments need to be reorganized from their original format to a monthly schedule.  Below is an example of the original data format:

**Original Cashflow Schedule**

```
Cashflow_Date     Principal     Interest
-------------     ---------     --------
2015-12-15        0             1000.00
2016-06-15        0             1000.00
2016-12-15        10000.00      1000.00
```

Below is the format that is needed:

**Desired Cashflow Schedule**

```
Cashflow_Date     Principal     Interest
-------------     ---------     --------
2015-12-15        0             166.667
2016-01-15        0             166.667
2016-02-15        0             166.667
2016-03-15        0             166.667
2016-04-15        0             166.667
2016-05-15        0             166.667
2016-06-15        0             166.667
2016-07-15        0             166.667
2016-08-15        0             166.667
2016-09-15        0             166.667
2016-10-15        0             166.667
2016-11-15        0             166.667
2016-12-15        10000.00      1000.00
```

Basically, months between payments from the original schedule need to be returned along with the original payment dates and the original payments need to be broken out into monthly amounts between the original payment dates (i.e. 1000/6=166.667 from 2015-12-15 to 2016-05-15).  The last payment date (in this case 2016-12-15) will stay as is.  The principal and interest payments are not guaranteed to be the same throughout the original schedule, so it is important to divide the payments appropriately.

The current process we have unfortunately uses a cursor and a loop inside the cursor (very bad I know) to produce the needed result set.  Can anyone provide any insight into a set based query that might be able to produce the same results much faster?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated scenario**

Per a question posted below, if a one time principal or interest payment is made in the original schedule, those payments are divided up accordingly.  For example, if a one time principal payment is made on 2016-06-15, then the monthly income schedule would reflect that in this way:

**Edge Case Desired Cashflow Schedule**

```
Cashflow_Date     Principal     Interest
-------------     ---------     --------
2015-12-15        0             166.667
2016-01-15        0             166.667
2016-02-15        0             166.667
2016-03-15        0             166.667
2016-04-15        0             166.667
2016-05-15        0             166.667
2016-06-15        208.33        166.667
2016-07-15        208.33        166.667
2016-08-15        208.33        166.667
2016-09-15        208.33        166.667
2016-10-15        208.33        166.667
2016-11-15        208.33        166.667
2016-12-15        10000.00      1000.00
```

Comment: what happens when ONE time regular payments are made and also how do we handle Principal only payments ? Can you show expected output for these edge cases or irregular cases ?

Comment: Gladly.  In the cases you specify, the payments will need to be divided among the months that follow the original payment until the next scheduled payment.  For example, if a principal payment is made on 6/15/2016 in the amount of $1250, that month and every month up to the next scheduled payment month will receive a portion of the original $1250 ($208.33 per month principal payment until 2016-12-15).

Comment: could you please represent that in a tabular fashion by editing your question?

Comment: Yes, please see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you want something like this:

```
DECLARE @ TABLE (Cashflow_Date DATE, Principal DECIMAL (10,2), Interest DECIMAL (10,2));
INSERT @ VALUES ('2015-12-15', 0, 1000.0), ('2016-06-15', 1250.0, 1000.0), ('2016-12-15', 10000.0, 1000.0);

SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n.number, Cashflow_Date) Dates
     , MAX(Principal) / ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MONTH, Cashflow_Date, nextDate), 1) Principal
     , MAX(Interest) / ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MONTH, Cashflow_Date, nextDate), 1) Interest
FROM (
    SELECT t.Cashflow_Date
         , t.Principal
         , t.Interest
         , X.nextDate
    FROM @ t
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT MIN(Cashflow_Date)
        FROM @
        WHERE Cashflow_Date > t.Cashflow_Date) X(nextDate)) t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT number
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE type='P') n
WHERE n.number < ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MONTH, Cashflow_Date, nextDate), 1)
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, n.number, Cashflow_Date), nextDate, Cashflow_Date
ORDER BY DATEADD(MONTH, n.number, Cashflow_Date);
```

You need some sort of tally table to fill in the dates between the first date and the next date, then you just need to average out the principal and interest based on the number of months between the first date and the next date.

Comment: That's great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See if this will help you get started towards getting rid of cursors

**(Not tested for all scenarios)**

```
/*
one time setup

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tbl]
(
    [cf] [date] NOT NULL,
    [pmt] [int] NOT NULL,
    [intrest] [int] NOT NULL
) 
GO

insert into dbo.Tbl values ( '2015-12-15', 0 , 1000)
insert into dbo.Tbl values ( '2015-06-15', 0 , 1000)
insert into dbo.Tbl values ( '2016-12-15', 1000 , 1000)

*/


select Top 13 b.* , intrest/6.0 as int_mnthly, DATEADD(Month,Mnth, cf) as cf_mnthly
from dbo.Tbl b
cross join 
( 
    select 1 as Mnth Union ALL
    select 2 as Mnth Union ALL
    select 3 as Mnth Union ALL
    select 4 as Mnth Union ALL
    select 5 as Mnth Union ALL
    select 6 as Mnth 
) a
order by cf_mnthly
```